# How do you sync contacts between Outlook and Windows Live?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, windows-live

Does anyone know how to sync contacts in Outlook with Windows Live contacts? I’ve got Outlook Connector but all that does is makes Live contacts visible in Outlook and doesn’t actually sync them.

Comment: The problem with both these solutions is that Windows Live Contacts can only hold 1000 items - severely limited :-(

Answer (score 4):

[Paul Thurrott](http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/wlc_to_iphone.asp) has a few thoughts about this:

> Yes, you can actually change a Windows Live account to be the default account in Microsoft Outlook. You do so by visiting Tools, Account Settings and then the Data Files tab in the Account Settings dialog. If you select your Windows Live account (typically named username@live.com) and click the Set as Default button, you will see your Windows Live account data by default when you click the Mail, Calendar, Contacts, or Tasks shortcut buttons in Outlook. And if your Windows Live account is your main email account, or your only email account, you may want to do just this

It seems if you set your Windows Live to your default in Outlook, you should be able to move your contacts over to Windows Live contacts and sync them immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use soocial.com . 
You can then sync between Outlook and Soocial
as well as between Soocial and Windows Live.

So your sync will look somwhat like:

Outlook Contacts on PC <==> soocial.com contacts <==> Windows Live contacts

( I have been trying soocial out for the last few weeks. It was working like a charm, until about last week. Since then, its not been syncing with Outlook. It does still sync with Windows Live. I am hoping its a bug that will get fixed soon. )

http://www.soocial.com